# Balance columns at new pages in multicol

Tags: multicol

I am creating a document that uses a mixture of 1- and 2-column layouts with the `multicol` package. I would like to be able to balance the columns and have some text spanning both columns before resuming the 2-column layout. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[Some text that will span both columns and fill the entire page width.]

\lipsum

% \end{multicols}
\newpage
% \begin{multicols}{2}[Some text that will span both columns and fill the entire page width.]

\lipsum

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

When `\newpage` is called, is immediately begins a new page and does not balance the column. The effect I would like to achieve is shown if the two lines above are uncommented. Then, ending the `multicol` environment and beginning it again (with the option argument to span both columns) works. However, this ends the current group, so local definitions are lost *and* I cannot proceed if this balancing happens within another environment.

Is it possible to achieve the desired effect, balancing the columns at a specific point with some interceding text?

[I am using the `multicol 1.8a` package from the SVN site.]

Answer (score 3):

hmm this does what you ask, showing the split in the scope of a local declaration and a nested enumerate environment. However if your real case is as you show with a single line it would be simpler to consider the full width text as part of the page heading and just use a custom page style. Then it would also work with automatic page breaking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}



\setbox0\vbox{{\hsize\dimexpr(\textwidth-\columnsep)/2\relax
\columnwidth\hsize
\linewidth\hsize

\footnotesize% arbitray declaration to show scope
\lipsum


\begin{enumerate}
\item one
\pagebreak
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum
\par}}

\setbox2=\vsplit0 to \maxdimen

\begin{multicols}{2}[Some text that will span both columns and fill the entire page width.]
\unvbox2
\end{multicols}
\newpage
\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}[Some text that will span both columns and fill the entire page width.]
\unvbox0
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does work but I need to brush up on vsplit. I'll accept this if I can't come up with any other ideas in the next day or so.